# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined?

Tags: npm, npm-install

My npm version and node version are not the same.

```
 node -v v14.15.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:688:35)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:676:5
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm@latest"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Project\theradoc-UI\theradoc\web\ng-src
npm ERR! node -v v14.15.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\theradoc-UI\theradoc\web\ng-src\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

When I run the command npm install -g npm@latest, it shows the error that I copy pasted above. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue. You may or may not have two installations of Node.js.

- First try cleaning the cache by running `npm cache clean`
- If the previous suggestion doesn't solve your issue then you probably have two versions installed. I'd suggest you to  delete the npm in AppData, uninstall both versions of Node.js, and install the latest versions.

Comment: You mean deleting AppData/Roaming/npm folder ?

Comment: Here, this will help you [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/f43tq6/is_there_a_way_to_uninstall_all_node_and_npm/fhoxt2c?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)